# NFC Door Key in Google Wallet

Tags: android, locking, nfc, wallet

I am about to develop an Android app for a customer.

The user of this application should be able to open his room door (e.g. hotel) through NFC. Now I want to make it as convient as possible for the user and integrate that key into the google wallet to prevent opening the app to unlock the door.

Does anyone have experience with that? It would be totally fine to find a solution together with google if this is necessary.

Already looked into the wallet documentation and didn't find any helpful information

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

No official announcement yet, but there is code for "HotelCard" in the Play services APK, so the feature is coming. You could contact Google through the Pay & Wallet Console to see if they'd give you early access to development documentation.

Comment: Thanks! That sounds helpful. Where and how exactly did you find that?

Comment: @3PNX You can download the APK from APKMirror and use Studio to decrypt and search through its contents.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).